# Any contenteditable helper plugins for Firefox/Webkit?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webkit, dom-events, contenteditable

I'm currently working to build a CMS for a client where the editing page looks **exactly** like the rendered page.

Hence I don't want an iframe based WYSIWYG, I am looking for something of a wrapper for `contenteditable` which irons out the differences between Firefox and Webkit.

For instance an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press in Firefox results in a `<br/>` tag while the same event in Webkit results in it being enclosed in a `<div>` tag.

If you don't have suggestions for an editor, then can you help me solve this problem? The way I fixed it first was to check the `onkeyup` event and then use the `execCommand` "*undo*" and then *insertHtml* `<br/>`.

That works fine, but the problem is if the user is in a list, and they press enter they expect to have a next list element created but end up with a line break. How do I detect what's the location of the caret when the enter key is being fired so that I can skip the `<br/>` insertion behavior ?

Ideally I wouldn't even want a `<br/>` rather the text block to be encapsulated in a `<p>` tag for SEO purposes, but I wasn't able to solve that as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Aloha editor is nice. Google it.

Comment: @Nikhil Thanks for the vote. I also wrote KitGUI.com which is a CMS that has on page editing. You can see it in my profile. I'm using Aloha editor as my end goal in terms of how rich it is on the page. I do have an inline editor but its very plain.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of niggly little differences between the browsers when it comes to content editing. I don't know of any library that irons out all the differences and I suspect that anyone writing such a library would simply write a browser-based WYSIWYG editor. That being the case, your best bet is probably to look at how the big open source editors such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) and [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration property called 'content_editable' in the source code of TinyMCE v3.5.2. This flag prevents an iframe from getting rendered. The published documentation doesn't say anything about this flag. I presume it is because the flag might not have been deeply tested.

I invoked TinyMCE on a contenteditable div and disabled all TinyMCE UI. Basic functionality seems to be working fine.

Init Options:

```
$('#editor').tinymce({
        script_url: '/tinymcecustom/tiny_mce_jquery.js',
        content_editable: true,
        theme: "simple"
    });
```

Html MarkUp:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" style="height: 900px"></div>
```

EditorTemplate.js (inside the theme folder):

```
(function () {
tinymce.create('tinymce.themes.SimpleTheme', {
    init: function (ed, url) {
        this.editor = ed;
    },
    renderUI: function (o) {
        return {
            editorContainer: this.editor.id
        };
    }
});
tinymce.ThemeManager.add('simple', tinymce.themes.SimpleTheme); })();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex area which you will struggle with to get right. Also if you are allowing users to Paste content then using an iFrame is the best way to ensure valid results and not mess up the page.

Aloha editor, TinyMCE etc. are rather big and bloated. I suggest you have a look at WYSIHTML5 https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5, http:www.createjs.org or for something simpler https://github.com/mquan/freshereditor however I don't recommend this simplistic approach.